# Why do I have problem rendering this conditional JSX?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx, redux-toolkit

I have a problem conditionally showing JSX in React.

I want to show the Login form when the user is not logged in, and show an h1 when the user is logged in.
However, when I log in, the login form stays and the h1 doesn't appear. Why does this happen?

■App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './Views/Login/Login';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => {
    state.auth.loggedIn;
  });

  return (
  <div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    {isLoggedIn && <h1>LoggedIn</h1>}
    {!isLoggedIn && <Login />}
  </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

■index.js(store)

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from './auth-slice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { auth: authReducer},
});


export default store;
```

■auth-slice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: { admin: false, loggedIn: false },
  reducers: {
    login(state, action) {
    const { name, password } = action.payload;
    state.loggedIn = true;
    state.admin = true;
    console.log(name, password, state.loggedIn);
    },
  },
});

export default authSlice.reducer;
export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), if you use curly braces then you have to write a **return statement**.

Otherwise, implicitly a function returns `undefined`.
So in your case `isLoggedIn` is always undefined. A [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) which means always the Login form will show.

```
const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => 
    state.auth.loggedIn;
  );
```

Comment: This totally worked! Thank you! I didn't know without a return statement, the returned value would be undefined...  learned something new today!

Comment: Glad. Have a look at the MDN link for arrow functions i have added. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer.